# os.system run python script with arguments and parameters

Tags: python, json, csv, os.system

Hello I'm trying to run a python script inside another python script and I'm trying to do it with os.system(). The problem is that this script is a json to csv convertor and it has 2 arguments (that they are the directories of the input of the json files and the output the directory of the csv files) and then it has the --include and --ignore that have to do with the data of json that we want to transfer in the csv file. So basically when I run it on the terminal (and it works there) it looks like this:

```
python file/tmp/python/json_to_csv.py -i results/2.json -o results/csv_folder/2.csv --include metadata.audio_properties.* metadata.tags.musicbrainz_recordingid.0 lowlevel.* rhythm.* tonal.* --ignore *.min *.min.* *.max *.max.* *.dvar *.dvar2 *.dvar.* *.dvar2.* *.dmean *.dmean2 *.dmean.* *.dmean2.* *.cov.* *.icov.* rhythm.beats_position.*  --add-filename
```

Inside ipython I tried something like this:

```
os.system(“essentia/src/examples/python/json_to_csv.py -i results/24.mp3.json -o results/csv_folder/24.csv --include metadata.audio_properties.* metadata.tags.musicbrainz_recordingid.0 lowlevel.* rhythm.* tonal.* --ignore *.min *.min.* *.max *.max.* *.dvar *.dvar2 *.dvar.* *.dvar2.* *.dmean *.dmean2 *.dmean.* *.dmean2.* *.cov.* *.icov.* rhythm.beats_position.*  --add-filename”)
```

or this:

```
os.system(CONVERTOR + ' "' + jsons + '" "' + csvs + '"')
```

but nothing worked. Does anyone have any idea how this could work? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: curly quotes `“` change them to `"` and try again.

Comment: No that doesn't seem to be the problem! It still gives errors like import command not found

Answer (score 0):

The right one was this after all:

```
subprocess.call(["json_to_csv.py", "-i", "json_file", "-o", "csv_file", "--include", "metadata.audio_properties.* metadata.tags.musicbrainz_recordingid.0 lowlevel.* rhythm.* tonal.*", "--ignore", "*.min *.min.* *.max *.max.* *.dvar *.dvar2 *.dvar.* *.dvar2.* *.dmean *.dmean2 *.dmean.* *.dmean2.* *.cov.* *.icov.* rhythm.beats_position.*", "--add-filename"])
```